# Badge for tags : how are they chosen?

Tags: support, tags, badges, tag-badges

Some tags have associated badges (bronze, silver, gold). Some tags have not.

How is it decided? Is there a privilege to propose a new badge?

Comment: Every tag has all three badges. Which tag doesn’t have one? Note that the badge lists only display tag badges that have been awarded at least once, and you can only track the _next level_ of a tag badge, but it doesn’t mean that they don’t exist.

Comment: For example [html5-template] has no badge on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be eligible for tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work), at which point badges will automatically be awarded to all users who satisfy the badge requirements.
  ([html5-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-template), at the time of posting this, only appears on 68 questions)
- You can't "track" a tag (on your profile) which you haven't posted any questions or answers in.
- There may not be anyone who's gotten one of the badges yet (although I'm not sure which views this would affect).
- You must meet the badge requirements to get the badge ([there is a number of answers requirement of 20/80/200 in addition to a score requirement, on answers, of 100/400/1000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)).

Comment: I have a score of 100 with the html5-template tag on SO but I can't track it yet

Comment: @Supersharp See edit.